# Laravel Login not working, showing intermediate page

Tags: php, laravel, docker, authentication, session

Laravel login not working but showing the below intermediate page

[image]

It happens only in the production server which is an oracle cloud instance with docker on it and working after server restart and again returns back after some hours.

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3'

networks:
 laravel:

services:
 nginx:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
   ports:
    - "80:80"
   volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html:delegated
   depends_on:
    - PHP
   networks:
    - laravel
   restart: always
  MySQL:
   image: mysql:5.7
   tty: true
   ports:
    - "3306:3306"
   environment:
    MYSQL_USER: sdgf
    MYSQL_DATABASE: sdgsdf
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: dsfgsdf
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dsfgsfg
    SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    SERVICE_NAME: MySQL
   networks:
    - laravel
   volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
   restart: always
 PHP:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: php.dockerfile
   args:
    - USER_ID=1001
    - GROUP_ID=1001
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www/html:delegated
   - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  networks:
   - laravel
  restart: always

 artisan:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: php.dockerfile
   args:
    - USER_ID=1001
    - GROUP_ID=1001
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www/html:delegated
  working_dir: /var/www/html
  user: laravel
  entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
  networks:
   - laravel
volumes:
  mysql-data:
   driver: local
```

php.ini file

```
max_execution_time = 120
;extension=php_gd2.dll
upload_max_filesize = 40m
post_max_size = 50m
memory_limit=1024M
```

Login method in Login controller

```
public function postAdminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'], 'role' => Constants::$ADMIN_USER])) {
            return redirect()->route('adminHome');
        }
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'], 'role' => Constants::$METER_READER])) {
            return redirect()->route('adminHome');
        }
//        return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Login Failed']);
    }
```

I believe there is no mistake in the code and it was working perfectly in cpanel hosting for two years but the error comes up when hosting changed to cloud+docker setup.
I also have a doubt if it is because of any session-related issues. I have tried both file and database session in laravel but nothing fixes the issue.

Please let me know if anyone comes across similar issues, thanks.

Comment: add ob_start() @ the start of `public/index.php` file to see if it will work or not , then lets go to the next step

Comment: Hi John, I have tried adding ob_start() in index.php but no change, what we can do next

Answer (score 1):

This is a bot hack.

To fix, change from this:

```
"9000:9000"
```

To this:

```
"127.0.0.1:9000:9000"
```

This will limit access to localhost.

Comment: Oh my god. I've been looking for this so long and it's exactly the fix. Any explanation why this is working/happening?

Comment: Hello @tom203, I'm glad that's helped you. I was searching for hours to fix this. The reason is that there is a security issue that permit hacker / bots to modify headers and when they did this, it broke the authentification. The idea is to prevent them to do this by limitation of the access of the php container to the localhost.